# Displaying a Button at particular co-ordinates

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

How to display Button or a JButton at a particular coordinates say (x,y) of a window ?

Comment: Don't do this. Learn how to use [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to position components so your code will be easier to maintain and portable across platforms.

Comment: Layouts, particularly using layout padding and borders (most relevant `EmptyBorder`), can do this job better than setting an absolute location.

Answer (score 4):

Though you can use [setLocation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation%28int,%20int%29),

> I would strongly suggest [using a Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html), because while using a layout manager, though you can provide size and alignment hints, a container's layout manager has the final say on the size and position of the components within the container, believe me ***this can save you*** at times!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a reason that you don't want to use any of the existing LayoutManagers in the JDK, you might think about creating your own LayoutManager, specific to your application

It is pretty easy - just subclass FlowLayout, and in the doLayout method, call the setBounds for your button (and any other components).

That way you can specify the exact position assuming your expected container size, yet retain control to reposition the button in case the container is reduced or enlarged,

Comment: See also [*Creating a Custom Layout Manager*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use setBounds() to specify x,y position and width and height.

You will have to set Containers' layout to null, then you will have total control of positioning components within that.

See http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/ for examples

Comment: You mean that a scenario that this could be useful does not exist? How do you know what he's trying to do? Isn't it possible that Layout Managers could be mixed with an absolute Layout?

Comment: See [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374) for answers to those questions and more.

Comment: -1 for linking to "tutorial" (hach... ) that gets it completely wrong. @user905374 - no null layout and no mixing. In Swing (and AWT) that's a rule with so near to 100% that seeing the remaining gap requires highest resolution optics :-)

Comment: @kleopatra : No doubt, setting layout to null is a Debatable issue. But then a thing comes to my mind, that whatever exists, must have a PURPOSE, a REASON. One can never say, where setting layout to null can be useful. No doubt it's not a good practise, but again, we cann't simply say it is completely useless. One must be aware of every aspect of the language, so i won't say telling someone that it can be set to null, is in anyway wrong.  Regards.

Comment: @GagandeepBali yeah, there's always that ppb corner case - but that's not a reason to send anybody into that corner without an extremely strong reason ;-) Sending newbies there (as that horrible tutorial linked above) is a crime.

Comment: @kleopatra : A CRIME :-), isn't that a bit harsh a word ? Given that the provider, shared his knowledge on the question being asked, just that he failed to mention the PROS and CONS of using layout to null.  Regards